# Hiding navbar after clicking on link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

Recently, I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXkqy0b4M5g&t=141s) tutorial to make a responsive navbar.
Though, he doesn't explain how to close the navbar after clicking on a link (you have to click on the link that will take you to a section of the page, and then dismiss the navbar using the burger menu, quite cumbersome)

I have left a snippet of the code that is unfortunately not going to run properly on the web. If you have any idea of how i can complete my js, please tell me about it.
thanks in advance!

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li')


  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //Toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`
      }
    });
    //burger animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
header {
  height: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 998;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 5vh;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  z-index: 998;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 998;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: var(--clr-neutral-000);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  z-index: 998;
}

.nav-links li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5em;
  background: var(--clr-neutral-000);
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.5vh;
}

.nav-links a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
  right: 50%;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: var(--clr-neutral-000);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1366px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .nav-links li a {
    color: var(--clr-neutral-000);
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    background-color: var(--clr-neutral-100);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 990;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="assets/Monograms/JC Monogram Outline Stroke (Fill) Black 32x32.svg" alt="JC modern monogram black" class="logo">
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event-listener to the "nav-links" element.

When you click on a link, a click will trigger on both the link itself (navigating) and on the parent container (closing the menu).

```
    const navLinksContainer = document.querySelector('.nav-links')

    navLinksContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      // We only toggle the menu if the event target is the anchor tag...
      if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a'){
        // Your toggle code goes here...   
      }
  });
```